# Популярность Java

Tags: java

Вопрос довольно глупый, но прошу не смеяться. В чем причина популярности Java? Почему она получила такое широкое распространение?

Comment: Вопрос совсем не глупый и не праздный

Answer (score 8):

Вероятнее всего из-за ее абсолютной платформонезависимости (наличие ява машины) и довольно развитой парадигмы ООП.

В освоении java тоже довольно простой язык, тоже самое можно сказать и касательно портирования с java на другие ЯП при условии знания оных.

P.s: если где-то не прав, прошу поправить

Comment: Насчет простоты абсолютно не согласен. Набор операторов прост. Количество реализованных (в библиотеках) классов (иерархий)  просто угнетающе велико.

Comment: Согласен, не считаю java простым в освоении языком...<br>
Базовые знания получить относительно легко, а вот углубляться нужно очень долго и усердно...

Comment: Это наверное так почти во всех распространенных языках. Язык сам по себе может быть небольшой и относительно несложный, а вот всякие библиотеки... С другой стороны, это дает большую функциональность. И не нужно, наверно, учить все подряд. Надо учить то, с чем планируешь работать.

Answer (score 8):

*Тема замусоленная, и наиболее полные ответы можно найти на англоязычных ресурсах.*

Рекомендую почитать [**Why do people use java?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213757/why-do-people-use-java) и [**Why is C# suddenly so popular?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575513/why-is-c-sharp-suddenly-so-popular)

*Вторая тема хороша сравнением подходов `Microsoft` и `Sun/Oracle` к развитию языка и платформы.*

Также обращайте внимание на комменты, поскольку в них чаще всего находятся очень дельные замечания  к основным тезисам ответов - например, про костыли на `java` при разработке кросс-платформенных приложений и тому подобные вещи, которые приходят с опытом.

Answer (score 8):

Ещё свои 5 копеек к популярности добавил garbage collector (сборщик мусора), система отвечающая за автоматическое освобождение памяти путём удаления объектов на которые уже нет ссылок, строгая типизация (спорно, есть программисты которым не нравится), отказ от множественного наследования в пользу интерфейсов(также спорно), огромный архив библиотек по всему интернету, которые можно свободно использовать и переделывать не опасаясь проблем с копирайтом, детальные подсказки и отлавливание ошибок на уровне компиляции...

Comment: Отсутствие множественного наследования, на мой взгляд, - плюс, т.к. может приводить к разным безобразиям, да и смысла в нем большого нет.

Присутствие GC - тоже, в принципе, хорошо, но все же было бы неплохо иметь механизм эксплицитного освобождения памяти. 

Строгая типизация - большой плюс. Сталкивался на перле с ошибками при путанице типов. Контекст переменной - ужасный и ненужный геморрой.

Answer (score 7):

Я выделю несколько принципиальных моментов:

1. Платформенная независимость (естественно с оговорками)
2. Автоматическая сборка мусора
3. И все методы по умолчанию (и почти всегда) виртуальные (в терминах С++)
4. Отсутствие множественного наследования
5. Правильный маркетинг языка (write once use everywhere). Изначально языком владела 1 компания Sun и она не допустила растекания спецификаций языка по множеству версий как это случилось с С/С++/SQL иже с ними.

**P.S.** Я считаю, что из всего этого списка наиболее важное свойство это п.3 - в самый раз для "быдлокодеров" не сумевших асилить "брульянтную" философию C++. Уверен, что 99% Java кодеров даже не подозревает об этом свойстве их любимого языка. И, кстати, это правильно!

Answer (score 6):

Хотел бы добавить что во многих известных языках реализация ООП делалась на основе Java, что лишь подтверждает то, насколько хорошо в java оно реализовано...
Ну и добавьте к этому кроссплатформенность, + разработка ПО для мобильных девайсов = успех...
Кстати - не так далеко от java C#, да и C++ будет жить вечно...

Comment: Вообще-то Java делали как безопасный C++. Так что ООП оттуда.

Comment: а где я писал обратное?О_о<br>
Если я написал многие языки это не означает что С++ в их числе, не?<br>
В php, action script, C# ООП от С++? нуну

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev... В java ООП сильно отличается от ООП С++....

Comment: @ВиталийВихляев, уж не знаю зачем вы отвечаете на комментарий четырёхлетней давности. Скажу лишь, ООП Java, что C++ одинаково неудобно, а мелкие различия не интересны.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы сказал - сбалансированность. Нет крупных недостатков, и нет сложных наворотов. Все очень стройно и логично. Когда разберешься - чувствуешь себя уверенно, не опасаясь подводных камней.

Answer (score 5):

Все плюсы джавы отходят на 2й план из-за ее простоты изучения, тут можно спорить, но не признать тот факт, что она проще в своем понимании от С++, С, [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET), Perl, Python и тд, нельзя

Comment: Уверяю вас, найдутся те, кто будет спорить как минимум по поводу Python'а. Кстати, простота изучения - кажущаяся. Чтобы достичь какого-то уровня, требуется немало времени. Правда, частично в зачёт идёт, если вы переодите, например, с C или C++.

Comment: ОМФГ в чем простота по сравнению с другими языками то?<br>
В чем существенный отличия от того же С#, ActionScript?<br>
Java проще perl? Это вообще обоссатся, я так подозревая вы в своем изучении java ушли не дальше `System.out.println("Hello World")`

Comment: C то чем сложен ? На мой взгляд из всех обсуждаемых языков он самый простой.

Comment: "Java проще perl" - вне всяких сомнений.

Comment: Ну это всего лишь имхо и я понимаю, что у всех разные предпочтения, но, если вспомнить с чем обычно сложности в С++ - рекурсия, УКАЗАТЕЛИ, библиотеки, деструкторы и тд, в яве все проще, структура либ, понятнее, деструкторов нету, указателей тоже...

Comment: Рекурсия, указатели и т.д. в С++ - это все ерунда. Самое сложное в нем - предотвращение утечек памяти при разрушении объектов и связанные с этим деструкторы.

На мой взгляд, Java унаследовала самую лучшую черту С - логичности и ясность. В перле все намешано и непоследовательно, к тому же море тонкостей, доступных только очень опытному взгляду. Но самый ужасный язык, с которым я имел дело, - Фортран.

Comment: На счет простоты изучения: всегда вспоминаю фразу известного музыканта сказанную о идеальном инструменте: "Идеальный инструмент просто для новичка и чрезвычайно сложен для профессионала". Мне кажется язык java полностью подходит под это описание.
Я изучал basic, pascal, c, asm, vb, js, java - из всего этого списка легче всего давалась в изучении java. При чем я делал это сам, с большой толстой книжкой в руках, без посторонней помощи и без наличия интернета